# Leaflet Popup with additional information from GeoJSON

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I want to bind the additional information from geojson to a leaflet marker popup. I looked up a few things from the leaflet documentation but it doesn't work.

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.9, 7.6], 11);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/5e4495ff4b0d454eb0443225198b7e6c/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 16
}).addTo(map);

var polygon = {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "name":"City BoundingBox",
        "style": {
            "color": "#004070",
            "weight": 4,
            "opacity": 1
        }
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [[
            [7.5,52.05],                
            [7.7,51.92],
            [7.6,51.84],
            [7.4,51.94],
            [7.5,52.05]
        ]]
    }
};

var myLayer = L.geoJson().addTo(map);
//myLayer.addData(polygon);

var popup = L.popup();

function onMapClick(e) {
    popup
        .setLatLng(e.latlng)
        .setContent("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString())
        .openOn(map);
}

map.on('click', onMapClick);

<?php 
    $mdjson = file_get_contents("http://xxx/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&outputFormat=JSON&request=GetFeature&typeName=xx:yy&maxFeatures=50");
    echo "var geojsonMD = ".$mdjson.";";    
?>

myLayer.addData(geojsonMD);

L.geoJson(geojsonMD, {
    style: function (feature) {
        return {color: feature.properties.color};
    },
    onEachFeature: function (feature, myLayer) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.description);
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

Hope you can help me.

Best regards.

Comment: Can you make it a bit clearer what you want to do? Do you want to combine the geoJson donwloaded from the service with the polygon you created yourself?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming the service returns data with similar properties as the polygon, you can indeed add them to one and the same layer.

```
var myLayer = L.geoJson(geojsonMD, {
     style: function (feature) {
         return feature.properties.style;
     },
     onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
         layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name);
     }
 })

myLayer.addData(polygon);
myLayer.addTo(map);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wn5Kh/ (without the downloaded data, for I do not have the URL)

If the `geojsonMD` has different feature properties, there's nothing wrong with adding two GeoJson layers. One for the data you retrieve from the service, and one with the polygon.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the Leaflet documentation, you should use the "onEachFeature" to attach a popup with the desired information to each feature of your GeoJson:

> The onEachFeature option is a function that gets called on each
>   feature before adding it to a GeoJSON layer. A common reason to use
>   this option is to attach a popup to features when they are clicked

You can use it this way:

```
var myLayer = L.geoJson(polygon, {
    onEachFeature: yourOnEachFeatureFunction
}).addTo(map);

function yourOnEachFeatureFunction(feature, layer){
    if (feature.properties.name) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name);
    }
}
```

In this example the popup will show the content of the property "name" for each clicked feature

Comment: But that's not what he wants. He wants to dynamically add some extra data to the json. I think.

Answer (score 1):

Now it works. I wanted leaflet automatically gets coords and feature information from a wfs and adding them to the map.

thats the working code and thanks for your help =)

```
<?php 
                    echo "var geojsonMD = ".$mdjson.";";    
?>

 myLayer.addData(geojsonMD);

 var myLayer = L.geoJson(geojsonMD, {
 style: function (feature) {
     return feature.properties.style;
 },
 onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {

        var strtype = '';

        if (feature.properties.mdtype == 0) {
            strtype = 'aaa';
        } else if (feature.properties.mdtype == 1) {
            strtype = 'bbb';
        }


     layer.bindPopup('<b>' + feature.properties.mdname + '</b><br>'
                        + strtype + '<br><br>'
                        + feature.properties.mdadress + '<br>'
                        + feature.properties.mdfon);
   }
   })
        myLayer.addTo(map);
```